# Call on method created in a loop always executes last method of the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node 0.8.8 together with express 3.0.

There is an object `checks` with a couple of methods and an empty object `middleware` which should now be filled with methods, one method for each method in `checks`, that basically executes its `check`-equivalent with a couple of additional arguments.

The code looks as follows:

```
var checks = {

  baz: function(req, callback) {
    console.log('baz');
    callback(true);
  },

  foo: function(req, callback) {
    console.log('foo');
    callback(true);
  },

  bar: function(req, callback) {
    console.log('bar');
    callback(true);
  }

};

var middleware = {};

for (var check in checks) {

  middleware[check] = function(req, res, next) {
    checks[check](req, function(result) {
      // ...
    });
  };

}
```

However, no matter what method of `middleware` I call, the method which wraps the last method of `checks` is executed. That means that either `middleware`, although the keys are correct, is filled with the same method, or every method call on `middleware` executes the last method.

```
middleware.baz({}, function(){}); // => 'bar'
middleware.foo({}, function(){}); // => 'bar'
middleware.bar({}, function(){}); // => 'bar'
```

When I execute the newly created function that is assigned to `middleware[check]`, the function is correct and wraps the one I expect. Even when I call the function assigned to `middleware[check]` from the last loop, the result is as expected.

```
for (var check in checks) {
  // ...
  middleware[check]({}, function(){});
}

// => baz
// => foo
// => bar
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once your `for` loop has finished, the value of `check` is whatever the last property of `checks` is. You need to capture the value of `check` at each iteration, and you can use a closure to do so:

```
for (var check in checks) {
  (function (check) {
    middleware[check] = function(req, res, next) {
      checks[check](req, function(result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
  }(check));
}
```

Also note that you should probably add a `hasOwnProperty` check to that loop as it will currently enumerate any enumerable properties that are set on the prototype of `checks`.

As a simple demonstration, have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37KCz/). Check the console, then uncomment the anonymous function expression and run the code again.